# Magnolia Module a code change is not included

Tags: module, updates, magnolia

I've trouble with an adaptation on a module.
I'm using  the vanityUrl module and adapted it to fit my needs. It worked as it should with all my adaptations to the java code.
But because a duplicated code snippet, the anchor-tag has been added twice. I fixed the code, but the changes aren't updated on the deployed server. I run it again locally, and the fix wasn't made there, so I started with debugging and the duplicated code was used. But after a deeper debugging, it was fixed and my fix worked. Because the server is outside my range, I'm not able to remote debug it. So I tried it with an update task for the module with this task:

`DeltaBuilder update142 = DeltaBuilder.update("1.4.2", "Update to version 1.4.2");
        update142.addTask(new BootstrapSingleModuleResource("Bootstrap new config", "Bootstrap folder/type definition in app.", "config.modules.magnolia-vanity-url.apps.vanityUrl.xml"));
        register(update142);`

Testing this locally it worked again. But on the server, the version number was updated but still the duplicated code is used.

In my opinion I could fix it with removing the module, make a clean install, adding the module again add make a clean install again. But becuase I've not the access to the server to make this, I'm searching another possibility to make the module using the fixed code.

I'm glad for any help.

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Tonio

Comment: If I understood it correctly, your module is already installed but you have to reinstall it with the new version update ? Is that what you want to achieve in the end ?

Comment: I thought about it further, you can easily remove a node or a property with a version update. Please let me know about your needs then I can point you to the proper task. cheers

Comment: What is the version of the module on the remote server? Is it less than 1.4.2? Where is the code that added duplicated tag? Did you remove it from the server? Or is it still there and possible executed after your update task was executed thus reverting your changes and reinserting duplicate?

Comment: The fix was on the server before i made the update to version 1.4.2, but it has no effect. At the moment the right code and the version 1.4.2 is on the server, but the fix don't work (localy it works as it should). 
@Ducaz035 yes, the module is already installed, but i want to get my fix worked on the server (at the moment the fixed code is there, but doesn't work). Removing a node don't help me, as the fix is in a java class, so it's not visible on magnolia.

Comment: @Jan the version on the server is 1.4.2 and the duplicated code is replaced with an fix on the server. The update was made after the fix, but it is only made one time to update the whole module, but it doesn't work as i thought.

Answer (score 0):

Okay now I see why the task is not executed, Firstly your version is already set to 1.4.2 so Magnolia will not think it as a update because its simply the same version on the instance. You should dump up the version of the module and register the delta with that bumped up version e.g. 1.4.3 in your case.

Comment: The update should have worked, as I didn't change the version number on magnolia, it was changed by the update to 1.4.2. But I'm trying it with setting back the version number to 1.4.1, so that the update takes play again. I will come back to your answer when the extern company restarts the server so i see the change.

Comment: In the update screen, you should be seeing which tasks are executed if that helps. Also depending on your Magnolia version, if you have higher than 5.4.5 you should be seeing those classes from Resource Files app. One thing has to be done there is that you should be adjusting 'magnolia.resources.classpath.observation.pattern'  property to accept .class files e.g.  ".*\\.(ftl|yaml|class)$"

Comment: Thx for the information, the update from 1.4.1 to 1.4.2 worked, but it didn't have any effect on the wrong executed code. As I use magnolia 5.4.6, I tried you soultion with `magnolia.resources.classpath.observation.pattern` with the given pattern, but in magnolia I didn't see any class files under "web-dev > ressources", are you sure about the correct pattern? It would be great to see the used class files in magnolia. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have those files loaded from file system? I imagined that they come from Classpath

Comment: I just double checked that it's not possible to get class files listed by Resources app due to some additional checks at info.magnolia.resourceloader.classpath.DefaultClasspathServiceConfigurations. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the further information, I will soon get remote debugging access, maybe I can then find more information about what code is used. Due to hollidays, this will not be in the next days, but i will come back with more details.

Comment: Just to inform you, I could solve the problem with remote-debugging on the server, since I debugged it, the correct code is used. But thanks for your help in finding out what's wrong.

Comment: @EagleT thanks for the update :) happy that you found your problem. Cheers